# jQuery reveal - Default Image

Tags: jquery

I have a real simple jQuery reveal function which loads an image into a DIV when a link is clicked.

```
$(function(){
jQuery(".gallery-item a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#imageBox").empty().append(
        jQuery("<img>", { src: this.href})
    );
});
});
```

Is there a way to add a default image so that when a page is loaded there is an image in the div already?

Comment: Can't you just add that to the HTML?

Comment: Just trigger a click on the first `<a>` on page load.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $(".gallery-item a").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var box = $("#imageBox").html('<img src="default.jpg" />');

        $("<img>", {src: this.href}).load(function () {
            box.empty().append(this);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting nothing from this one, until I click on one of the links, then the default image displays for a second before being replaced with the one I have clicked?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery(".gallery-item a").click(function(evt) {
        jQuery("#imageBox").empty().append(
           jQuery("<img />", { src: $(this).attr("href") })
        );
        return false;
    });
});​
```

**Edit for comment:**

Assuming that the url of the image is in the attribute "data-urlimage" Tag "a"

Html:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
 <a data-urlimage="/img/myimage.jpg" href="#">click here</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery(".gallery-item a").click(function(evt) {

         var img = new Image();
         img.src = $(this).data("urlimage");
         img.onload = function(){
             jQuery("#imageBox").empty().append(img);
         };

        return false;
    });
});​
```

[see image events](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/image.html)

**Edit:** see how to create better object "image"

Comment: With this method, where would I put the url for the image?  Would I replace the href?

Comment: I assumed you had the url of the image in the "href" attribute of the tag "a". If you can replace the "href" for what you want